# How to parse a ping result with regex

Tags: java, android, regex, ping

What I want is to parse the result of a ping, line by line. It's a bit tricky for me and tried a lot of things but well... I'm using the ping on Android.

For example:

```
PING google.com (173.194.35.9) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mil01s16-in-f9.1e100.net (173.194.35.9): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=33.0 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 33.086/33.086/33.086/0.000 ms
```

On the first line, I want the Ip address, the "56(84) bytes of data". On second line "64 bytes", 1,52,33.0 ms etc.

If a ping an IP directly, it changes a little bit

```
PING 192.168.0.12 (192.168.0.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.12: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.134 ms

--- 192.168.0.12 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.134/0.134/0.134/0.000 ms
```

But should work too !

And if I have a little explaination with an answer, it would be cool !

Thanks so much!

Comment: SO is not a coding service.  What did you try?

Comment: At the beginning I ping only an Ip adress, so I catched the line i was looking for, like [a-z-/\s=\d\.\d]+ for the last one, and then split on the middle of my informations to get the results. [a-z-/\\s=]+ for the last line again. But thoses regex are very generics. For example with the mil01s16-in-f9.1e100.net that contains number,-,. like the rest of the line.

Comment: Tip: You can make that parsing easier by running ping with the `-n` parameter. It will always output IP addresses instead of hostnames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Description

This expression will capture IP, bytes of data, bytes, ICMP_SEQ, ttl, time. I couldn't find `etc`.

```
^PING\b # match ping
[^(]*\(([^)]*)\) # capture IP
\s([^.]*)\. # capture the bytes of data
.*?^(\d+\sbytes)  # capture bytes
.*?icmp_seq=(\d+)  # capture icmp_seq
.*?ttl=(\d+)  # capture ttl
.*?time=(.*?ms)  # capture time
.*?(\d+)\spackets\stransmitted   # the rest of these lines will capture the other portions of the ping result
.*?(\d+)\sreceived
.*?(\d+%)\spacket\sloss
.*?time\s(\d+ms)
.*?=\s([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/(.*)\sms
```

[image]

## Example

Live Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/uEDoEZwY7U

**Sample Text**

```
PING google.com (173.194.35.9) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mil01s16-in-f9.1e100.net (173.194.35.9): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=33.0 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 33.086/33.086/33.086/0.000 ms


PING 192.168.0.12 (192.168.0.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.12: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.134 ms

--- 192.168.0.12 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.134/0.134/0.134/0.000 ms
```

**Sample Code**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("^PING\\b # match ping
[^(]*\\(([^)]*)\\) # capture IP
\\s([^.]*)\\. # capture the bytes of data
.*?^(\\d+\\sbytes) # capture bytes
.*?icmp_seq=(\\d+) # capture icmp_seq
.*?ttl=(\\d+) # capture ttl
.*?time=(.*?ms) # capture time
.*?(\\d+)\\spackets\\stransmitted
.*?(\\d+)\\sreceived
.*?(\\d+%)\\spacket\\sloss
.*?time\\s(\\d+ms)
.*?=\\s([^\\/]*)\\/([^\\/]*)\\/([^\\/]*)\\/(.*?)\\sms


",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
  int mIdx = 0;
    while (m.find()){
      for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
        System.out.println( "[" + mIdx + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
      }
      mIdx++;
    }
  }
}
```

**Capture Groups**

```
[0][0] = PING google.com (173.194.35.9) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mil01s16-in-f9.1e100.net (173.194.35.9): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=33.0 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 33.086/33.086/33.086/0.000 ms
[0][2] = 173.194.35.9
[0][2] = 56(84) bytes of data
[0][3] = 64 bytes
[0][4] = 1
[0][5] = 52
[0][6] = 33.0 ms
[0][7] = 1
[0][8] = 1
[0][9] = 0%
[0][10] = 0ms
[0][11] = 33.086
[0][12] = 33.086
[0][13] = 33.086
[0][14] = 0.000


[1][0] = PING 192.168.0.12 (192.168.0.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.12: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.134 ms

--- 192.168.0.12 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.134/0.134/0.134/0.000 ms
[1][3] = 192.168.0.12
[1][2] = 56(84) bytes of data
[1][3] = 64 bytes
[1][4] = 1
[1][5] = 64
[1][6] = 0.134 ms
[1][7] = 1
[1][8] = 1
[1][9] = 0%
[1][10] = 0ms
[1][11] = 0.134
[1][12] = 0.134
[1][13] = 0.134
[1][14] = 0.000
```

Comment: is this just on regex you have there ? Not sure I understand how you did this !

Comment: Yes, this is all just from the regex. The capture groups are populated by the regex engine as it finds matches. What bit are you not sure about?

Comment: Hi, add alternative with timestamp /ping -D -c 5 www.google.com output: [1564061349.511334] 64 bytes from www.google.com (216.58.201.164): icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=46.2 ms

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to parse the second line.

As such:

```
String domainPing = "64 bytes from mil01s16-in-f9.1e100.net (173.194.35.9): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=33.0 ms";
String ipPing = "64 bytes from 192.168.0.12: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.134 ms";
String wholeDomainPing = "PING google.com (173.194.35.9) 56(84) bytes of data.\r\n"+
            "64 bytes from mil01s16-in-f9.1e100.net (173.194.35.9): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=33.0 ms\r\n\r\n"+
            "--- google.com ping statistics ---\r\n"+
            "1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms\r\n" +
            "rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 33.086/33.086/33.086/0.000 ms";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
// "[digit] bytes"..... "from [ip]"               or "([ip])"
"(\\d+(?=\\sbytes)).*?(((?<=(from\\s))[\\d\\.]+)|((?<=\\()[\\d\\.]+(?=\\))))",
Pattern.MULTILINE
);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(domainPing);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Bytes: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("IP: " + matcher.group(2));
}
matcher = pattern.matcher(ipPing);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Bytes: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("IP: " + matcher.group(2));
}
matcher = pattern.matcher(wholeDomainPing);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Bytes: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("IP: " + matcher.group(2));
}
// etc...
```

Output:

```
Bytes: 64
IP: 173.194.35.9
Bytes: 64
IP: 192.168.0.12
Bytes: 64
IP: 173.194.35.9
```

**Edit** added example for whole input (first scenario) and `Pattern.MULTILINE` flag to the `Pattern`.

Comment: This is pretty nice! But if I'm looking for all information ? Like packet loss, min, max, avg. And the unit is static in your case!

Comment: @brunettia use Denomales' answer, or apply my answer to the full extend of your new scope. Also please consider editing your original post by mentioning that you actually need all the fields in the log, classified by type.